# iOS Simulator crashes after boot with "available but has no defaultDisplay"

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9

While running a project into the simulator, it crashes after booting:

```
Crash: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Device <redacted>, Booted) is available but has no defaultDisplay'
```

I already cleaned the project files and changed the iOS image but it crashes anyway. Any clue?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Close all simulators and just run

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

to restart the service. All simulators will launch as usual.

Comment: This answer is a true lifesaver, thank you. Sadly, this issue still persists in the final version of Xcode 10.

Comment: This helped, but I would like to know what causes this issue?

Comment: This glitch can manifest when toggling between different versions of Xcode. For example, it is repeatable when I initially open an app in Xcode 9.2, then later in Xcode 10. As @ricardopereira notes, killall will reset the sims.

Comment: saved it as an alias 
# Kill all simulator and restart the service
`alias ksim='sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService'`