# How to delete preferences for iOS Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

My Simulator is crashing upon launch. Even if I launch it manually, it will immediately quit. I have managed to Erase all contents, delete derived folders, deleted Xcode cache file. The problem still remains. If I run on a new account, the simulator runs and I notice that it has device frames etc... which I have turned off before. Does anyone know where the preference file for the Simulator is? I need to delete the preferences to start from new - device frames --- like it was just installed. Thanks!

Comment: Reset All Content and Settings... does exactly that. However, this seems like a problem that I'm having as well and the solution is likely this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51708445/3151675

Comment: That didn't work shucks. It crashes right away.

Comment: I uninstalled Xcode with app cleaner, ran in safe mode, the simulator crashes instantly. It's really strange, although it runs it doesn't appear in cmd-tab and the project says it's running but the run button doesn't indicate it's running.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Are you using the latest stable version of Xcode 10?

Comment: OMG 10.1 beta fixed it. It was some sort of bug with Xcode 10 GM. Wasted so much time!