# iOS Simulator Crash on Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode10, macos-mojave

Today, I've updated my iMac to macOS Mojave from macOS High Sierra. Since then I'm not able to open simulator. Every time I tried to open the simulator that crashes immediately. Whenever I tried to run the simulator via Xcode then Xcode shows this error

> Timed out waiting for the simulator application for iphonesimulator to become ready

[image]

Also, I tried to open the simulator directly and it's crash immediately. Here the gif (gif is a little bit slow) -

[image]
[image]

**System CPU & Memory Status** -

[image]

[image]

**Here some solution that I've tried but no luck -**

1. Clear iPhone Simulator Cache

   ```
   xcrun simctl erase all
   ```
2. Clear DerivedData

   ```
   ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
   ```
3. Clear iOS DeviceSupport

   ```
   ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/
   ```
4. Delete Xcode Preferences

   ```
   defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
   ```
5. Restart Xcode & System

---

**Update 1**

macOS Logs -

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Device iPhone XS (978302BA-5255-44CB-A77C-188071B99A7C, iOS 12.0, Booted) is available but has no defaultDisplay'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff33a9543d __exceptionPreprocess + 256
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff5f9a6720 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff33ab008e +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff35e4c55d -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 194
    4   Simulator                           0x000000010e7510da Simulator + 106714
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff60a24d4f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff60a25dcb _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff60a2c120 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + <…>
)
```

Comment: Have you tried to read the MacOS console log looking for relevant errors?

Comment: Have U tried the solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296360/ios-simulator-is-not-launching ?

Comment: @Kerberos macOS log added in the question

Comment: Similar problem resolved here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51708445/ios-simulator-crashes-after-boot-with-available-but-has-no-defaultdisplay

Comment: Yep, in this case try to follow the link's solution.

Comment: @Kerberos yes it's work but after this we need to add all simulator manually from `Windows` > `Device and Simulator`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This command should fix your issue (close sim before and open after):

```
sudo killall -10 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

After this, restart Xcode and if simulator not available then we need to add them manually from `Windows` > `Device and Simulators`

[image]

Comment: Now I'm getting this - No matching device (5523B6F8-F8BA-43FC-82F4-167CB54CEB34) in set at ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices

Comment: I think, Now, I need to manually add all simulator from `Windows` > `Device and Simulator` > `+`.

Comment: Yes, we need to manually add all simulator from `Windows` > `Device and Simulators`

Comment: I was switching between xcode 10 and 9.4 and at some point I ruined it for simulator not launching at all. This fixed my problem. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 0):

This resolved my issue

1. Force quit simulator by:-  **option + command + esc**  choose simulator and quit.
2. Quit Xcode and restart then it worked!